# Gmail forwarding after removing an account

Tags: gmail, email-forwarding

everyone. I have a Google Workspace Business account, I want to delete my mail, but after that I want to receive letters to another mail if someone writes to me on a remote email. How can I do this and is it possible?

I tried to configure Forwarding and POP/IMAP (it works only until I delete the mail), and I also tried to configure Default routing (it didn't help, or I don't know how to configure it correctly).